# how to subtract numbers with decimal point in php

Tags: php, codeigniter, backend

I need to subtract numbers in my table and i'm using php to get the result e.g 17.45 - 7.15. The result im getting is a whole number. How can i get the difference of the two numbers with its decimal point in two decimal places?

Here is the code i've been trying.

```
<td><?php echo  substr($list->m_time, 0,5) ?></td>
<td><?php echo  substr($list->mx_time, 0,5)?></td>
<td><?php echo substr($list->mx_time, 0,5) - substr($list->m_time, 0,5)?></td>
```

and here is my output:

[image]

Thanks and have a nice day!

Comment: may use time() ? http://de1.php.net/manual/de/function.time.php

Comment: you are using : in output table, use . in question.Make a confirmation about that.

Comment: @AdarshMPallickal Is that the reason why there is no decimal points showing? So how can i get the it?

Comment: my question is are you want to subtract time value or decimal values

Comment: i want to subtract time value. @AdarshMPallickal

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$result = floatval($list->mx_time) - floatval($list->m_time);
echo round(floatval($result),2);
```

I am giving somethng in other way around..

10:32 means 10 hours 32 mins

SO first we need to explode it like this

```
$start_time = explode(":",$m_time);   //where m_time = 10:32

$start_time_hr = $start_time[0];
$start_time_min = $start_time[1];

$start_tot_min = intval($start_time_hr*60) + $start_time_min;
```

similarly

```
$end_time = explode(":",$mx_time);   //where mx_time = 11:45

$end_time_hr = $end_time[0];
$end_time_min = $end_time[1];

$end_tot_min = intval($end_time_hr*60) + $end_time_min; //converting hour to min + min
```

now `$total_min_diff = intval($end_tot_min - $start_tot_min);`

then total `hr_diff = intval($total_min_diff/60);`

total `min_diff = intval($total_min_diff%60);`

There for time difference is $hr_diff Hours and $min_diff Minutes

i.e.

```
<?php echo "The total Difference Is : ".$hr_diff." Hours & ".$min_diff." Minutes.";?>
```

Comment: While suggesting code, include a brief about resolution you are suggesting!

Comment: @PareshMayani Thanks. I want to get the exact difference of the time with decimal places but i'm kind of lost what code should i use.

Comment: @SmrutiSingh im kind of lost at the last part. what will be the output of this?

Comment: Yes echo like this     <?php echo "The total Difference Is : ".$hr_diff." Hours & ".$min_diff." Minutes.";?>

Comment: @SmrutiSingh What if i want to add 15 minutes on start time as grace period when the time is below 10:00?

Comment: What do you mean by grace period? can you explain that thing tome, so that i can ubderstand?

Comment: @SmrutiSingh hi. Can you help me in this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25592415/build-a-table-of-date-using-php-in-codeigniter

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('17:13');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('10:32');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
$elapsed = $interval->format('%H:%i');
echo $elapsed;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use it like this

```
$result = $list->mx_time - $list->m_time;
echo round($result,2);
```

values are float, so don't use string functions

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I've tried it but the result is still the same. @PravinS

Answer (score 0):

Try using below code, that should for you

```
echo number_format((float)((float)$list->mx_time - (float)$list->m_time), 2, '.', '');
```

Or

```
echo number_format((float)($list->mx_time - $list->m_time), 2, '.', '');
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution but the output have decimal points, yes. but it didn't get the other exact amount. e.g 17:15 - 7:00 = 7.00